# Проверить предыдущее значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы, условия

Как проверить что предыдущее значение в списке больше 0?

```
ff = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Вот так проверяем что текушее ff значение больше 0:

```
for u in ff:
    if u > 0:
        print(1)
```

а как проверить **u предыдущее** (ff-1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохранять каждое значение (предположим, что для первого элемента (у которого нет предыдущего), предыдущее значение равно 0):

```
ff = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]
pred = 0
for u in ff:
    if pred > 0:
        print("do something")
    pred = u
    if u > 0:
        print(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

По индексу списка:

```
ff = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

for i in range(1, len(ff)):
    print(f'[{i}] curr: {ff[i]}, prev: {ff[i-1]}')
    if ff[i-1] > 0:
        print(1)
```

выведет:

```
[1] curr: 0, prev: 0
[2] curr: 0, prev: 0
[3] curr: 1, prev: 0
[4] curr: 0, prev: 1
1
[5] curr: 1, prev: 0
[6] curr: 0, prev: 1
1
[7] curr: 1, prev: 0
[8] curr: 1, prev: 1
1
[9] curr: 1, prev: 1
1
[10] curr: 0, prev: 1
1
[11] curr: 0, prev: 0
[12] curr: 0, prev: 0
[13] curr: 1, prev: 0
[14] curr: 0, prev: 1
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, наиболее **pythonic-way** - это через `zip` перебирать список сам с собой со сдвигом:

```
ff = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]
for prev,curr in zip([0]+ff,ff):
    print(prev, curr, 'both positive' if prev > 0 and curr > 0 else '')
```

Вывод:

```
0 0 
0 0 
0 0 
0 1 
1 0 
0 1 
1 0 
0 1 
1 1 both positive
1 1 both positive
1 0 
0 0 
0 0 
0 1 
1 0
```

Хотя что является предыдущим элементом для самого первого элемента списка - вопрос нетривиальный. :)  Я поставил там `0`, но вообще зависит от постановки задачи, что считать в этом случае "предыдущим элементом".